# Haskell monadic proof

Tags: haskell, monads

For the mathematical experts (I am not, nor a Haskell expert):

```
m >> k = m >>= \_ -> k
```

This 'monad' typechecks and compiles. Is this to mathematically proof that `m >> k` (omitting a return value) and `m >>= \_ -> k` (a monad with return, but a lambda without) are the same, or can I actually put values in? Just being curious. Not a blocking issue.

Comment: Mathematically, `>>` is defined in terms of `>>=` as in the equation above, so there's nothing to prove here. Also, even if both sides of an equation have the same type, we can't conclude that they are equal. E.g. `True = False` -- they have the same type `Bool`, but they are not equal.

Comment: If you put the actually value in, it become `>>=` and no longer be `>>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I a assume you are reading the following bit in the Prelude http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#%3E%3E

This is not a proof. This is more akin to the definition of a method in an OOP interface.

There in the definition of the `class Monad` (class in Haskell is more like an interface); it's defined that an operator `>>` should be defined. And a default definition is supplied. The default definition is `m >>= \_ -> k`.

Answer (score 2):

This is definition of function `>>` in infix form.

It is equivalent to more usual `(>>) m k = ...`.

Brackets here is to explain Haskell that we use operator in prefix form.